# cannot resolve method 'subscribeon(io.reactivex.scheduler)'

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm tring to use `rxjava` with retrofit in android studio, but when I add observable  in `compositedisposable`, I get this error:

```
cannot resolve method 'subscribeon(io.reactivex.scheduler)'
```

In fact, I am using this [sample code](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/11/android-rxjava-2-and-retrofit.html)

```
       @POST("/auth/register")
       Observable<Response>register(@Body User user);
```

Code

```
 private CompositeDisposable comdisposables= new CompositeDisposable();
 LoginRetrofitInterface requestInterface = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build().create(LoginRetrofitInterface.class);

     comdisposables.add(requestInterface.register(user)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::handleError));
```

and dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'

 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'

 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'

//implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:2.1.0'

// com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:2.2.0

 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'

 // RxJava

 implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'

 implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
```

Comment: Well what does `register` return?

Comment: what's the return type `register()`?

Comment: Try to refresh the project and dependencies in Android Studio. On the right hand side you can click Gradle icon and refresh/re-download dependencies. Alternatively, you can rebuild project from command line.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce              @POST("/auth/register")
    Observable<Response>register(@Body User user);

Comment: @RajasekaranM                                                                                                 @POST("/auth/register")
    Observable<Response>register(@Body User user);

Comment: is it `io.reactivex.Observable`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce                                                                                         tnx ,it is  android.database.Observable;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tnx to @EpicPandaForce for his/her helpful comments , error :cannot resolve method 'subscribeon(io.reactivex.scheduler)' solved.

`android.database.Observable` was imported instead of `io.reactivex.Observable`.